# Escribir en fichero mediante funcion hash y cubos

Tags: c, archivo, hash

Estoy haciendo una función que lee de un archivo binario una serie de elementos y tengo que pasarlos a otro archivo que los organiza en cubos mediante el método de dispersión hash. Aquí va la función:

```
int creaHash(char *fichEntrada,char *fichHash){

FILE *f;
FILE *fHash;
tipoAlumno alumno;
tipoCubo cubo;
int i = 0, registro, dni;
int numCubos =CUBOS+CUBOSDESBORDE;

creaHvacio(fichHash);

f = fopen(fichEntrada, "rb");
fHash = fopen(fichHash, "r+b");

while(!feof(f)){

    fread(&alumno, sizeof(tipoAlumno), 1, f);
    registro = atoi(alumno.dni) % CUBOS;

    //Buscamos el numero de cubo correspondiente
    fseek(fHash, registro*sizeof(tipoCubo), SEEK_SET);
    fread(&cubo, sizeof(tipoCubo), 1, fHash);

    if(cubo.numRegAsignados <= C){                  //Podemos escribir en el cubo porque no está lleno

        fseek(fHash, registro*sizeof(tipoCubo), SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(&cubo, sizeof(tipoCubo), 1, fHash);
        cubo.numRegAsignados++;
    }
    else{

        //cubo desbordado
    }
}




fclose(f);
fclose(fHash);
```

`tipoAlumno` y `tipoCubo` son dos estructuras. La función funcionaria así:

1. Leo `fichEntrada` y por cada entrada, obtengo un numero haciendo un `atoi` del dni.
2. Me desplazo hasta el cubo que corresponda con ese numero mediante `fseek`.
3. Leo el cubo, si no está desbordado, inserto el elemento que leí de `fichEntrada` y aumento el `numeroRefAsignados`.

Pero no escribe nada. Algo me estoy dejando que no encuentro. Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

Es posible que el proceso esté fallando en cualquiera de las operaciones de `fopen`, `fread`, `fseek` o `fwrite` pero dado que no compruebas si las operaciones funcionan no puedes saberlo.

- **Si [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) falla**: Se devuelve un puntero nulo.
- **Si [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) falla**: La posición del puntero de lectura del archivo queda en un estado indeterminado. La llamada a la función devuelve la cantidad de elementos leídos, si sucedió un error durante la lectura ésta cantidad será menor a la que se solicitó leer.
- **Si [`fseek`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) falla**: Devoverá un valor diferente a `0` y el puntero de lectura del archivo no se modifica.
- **Si [`fwrite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) falla**: Dado que la llamada a la función devuelve la cantidad de elementos escritos, si sucedió un error durante la escritura ésta cantidad será menor a la que se solicitó escribir.

Sabiendo esto, podríamos modificar tu código para que informase de en qué punto está fallando:

```
int creaHash(char *fichEntrada,char *fichHash){
    FILE *f = fopen(fichEntrada, "rb");
    FILE *fHash = fopen(fichHash, "r+b");

    tipoAlumno alumno;
    tipoCubo cubo;

    int i = 0, registro, dni;
    int numCubos =CUBOS+CUBOSDESBORDE;

    if (f && fHash){

        creaHvacio(fichHash);

        while(!feof(f)){

            if (fread(&alumno, 1, sizeof(tipoAlumno) f) == sizeof(tipoAlumno)){
                registro = atoi(alumno.dni) % CUBOS;

                //Buscamos el numero de cubo correspondiente
                if (fseek(fHash, registro*sizeof(tipoCubo), SEEK_SET)){
                    printf("Fallo al mover el puntero de lectura de fHash\n");
                }
                else{
                    if (fread(&cubo, 1, sizeof(tipoCubo), fHash) == sizeof(tipoCubo)){
                        if(cubo.numRegAsignados <= C){ //Podemos escribir en el cubo porque no está lleno
                            cubo.numRegAsignados++;
                            if (fwrite(&cubo, 1, sizeof(tipoCubo), fHash) == sizeof(tipoCubo)){
                                //todo bien
                            }
                            else{
                                printf("Fallo en la escritura de cubo\n");
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            //cubo desbordado
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("Fallo en la lectura de cubo\n");
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                printf("Fallo en la lectura de alumno\n");
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("No se pudieron abrir los archivos!\n");
    }
}
```

El código es más engorroso pero no debería pasar por alto ningún error y te podrá informar de qué problema tienes. Para que ésto sea posible he hecho los siguientes cambios:

1. Comprobar que `f` y `fHash` contienen punteros no nulos: De lo contrario alguno de ellos habrá fallado al abrir `fichEntrada` o `fichHash`.
2. Invertir los argumentos `size` y `count` en las llamadas a `fread` y `fwrite`: De esa manera en lugar de leer/escribir un `tipoAlumno`/`tipoCubo` leemos tantos bytes como ocupen esas estructuras, si la lectura es correcta se leerá su tamaño al completo.
3. Comprobar que `fseek` ha funcionado.
4. Eliminé el `fseek` adicional dentro de la comprobación de desbordamiento de cubo, el puntero ya estaba en la posición al que le pedías que se desplazara.
5. Aumento el recuento de asignados del cubo antes de escribirlo: De no hacerlo el recuento siempre irá un valor por detrás.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda. Encontré el fallo, y era una cosa tan "simple" como que no estaba añadiendo el alumno que leí al cubo. Me faltaba un: cubo.reg[i] = alumno, ya que reg[] es una colección de alumnos dentro de la definición de cubo.